# Replace all columns values with values from single column - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table:

| index | asin | salesRank | categories | also_viewed | buy_after_viewing | also_bought |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0001048791 | {'Books': 6334800} | [['Books']] | [**B0036FO6SI**, B000KL8ODE] | **B0036FO6SI** | 0000032050 |
| 1 | **B0036FO6SI** | {'Movies & TV': 376041} | [['Movies & TV', 'Movies']] | NaN | NaN | NaN |

And i need this:

| index | asin | salesRank | categories | also_viewed | buy_after_viewing | also_bought |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0001048791 | {'Books': 6334800} | [['Books']] | [**1**, B000KL8ODE] | **1** | 0000032050 |
| **1** | **1** | {'Movies & TV': 376041} | [['Movies & TV', 'Movies']] | NaN | NaN | NaN |

If someone has any clue it would be great thanks!
**btw**: The dataset is huge so faster is better

Comment: you are replacing **B0036FO6SI** string with **1**, as replacement value. what you meant by *single column*

Comment: I want to replace all values following index columns values

Comment: what you meant by *following index columns*?

Answer (score 0):

is that what you're looking for?

```
df.replace(r'B0036FO6SI','1', regex=True)
```

```
    index   asin    salesRank   categories  also_viewed     buy_after_viewing   also_bought
0   0   0001048791  {'Books': 6334800}  [['Books']]     [1, B000KL8ODE]     1   32050.0
1   1   1   {'Movies & TV': 376041}     [['Movies & TV', 'Movies']]     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Kind of cause i need it to be applied to every row and not be expensive cause of the size of the dataset.

Comment: @joacogomez, is it a replacement of that one string across the DF? apart from the performance concern, is the result what you expected? the description and response was not clear.